# Do gravitational vawes deplete energy even if there's nothing they can affect?

Tags: orbital-motion, gravitational-waves, thought-experiment

I've read multiple times that one of consequences of gravitational waves being a thing is, that they make any orbit unstable. As long as the two or bodies orbit around each other, they create gravitational waves and that costs some energy.

Most of the time we consider gravity only as long as multiple objects are concerned. But unless gravitational waves magically know how much mass is around them, they should always steal the same amount of energy.

If there are two bodies orbiting each other in empty universe, do they lose energy to gravitational waves? Where does that energy go?

Comment: The energy goes into the waves, but you can relax... the amount of energy the Earth is losing to the gravitational waves it creates as it revolves around the sun is marginal. It won't crash us into the sun anytime soon.

Comment: @CuriousOne I was more concerned about the *at infinity* situation where eventually, nothing can orbit or rotate. That seems to mean that eventually, universe should literally stop moving.

Comment: yes, try look for quasi normal modes in the literature

Comment: @TomášZato: Well, not stop moving. But certainly planetary motion will a quite boring. Also given that we have black holes at the center of more or less every galaxy, in the long run everything in the galaxy would eventually fall into these. But these hawking radiate and will also evaporate, so at the end of the (very looong day) the universe will just be a (very cold) soup of radiation again.

Comment: Yes, that's part of the ultimate heat death scenario... all matter will, eventually, be converted to radiation, including gravitational waves. One could even ask if a hypothetical process exists that converts photons into gravitons.